# How to Sum the 1st record of one column with the 2nd record of another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying the Sum the 2nd record of one column with the 1st record of another column and store the result in a new column

Here is the example SQL Server table

```
Emp_Code   Emp_Name    Month          Opening_Balance   
 G101      Sam          1              1000              
 G102      James        2              -2500             
 G103      David        3              3000     
 G104      Paul         4              1800     
 G105      Tom          5              -1500
```

I am trying to get the output as below on the new `Reserve` column

```
Emp_Code   Emp_Name    Month          Opening_Balance    Reserve
 G101      Sam          1              1000              1000       
 G102      James        2              -2500             -1500         
 G103      David        3              3000               1500
 G104      Paul         4              1800               3300
 G105      Tom          5              -1500              1800
```

Actually the rule for calculating the `Reserve` column is that

1. For `Month-1` it's the same as `Opening Balance`
2. For rest of the months its `Reserve for Month-2` = `Reserve for Month-1` + `Opening Balance for Month-2`

Comment: Please tag your question with the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would do:

```
select t.*,
       sum(opening_balance) over (order by [Month]) as Reserve
from t;
```

In earlier versions, you would do this with a correlated subquery or `apply`:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.opening_balance) from t t2 where t2.[Month] <= t.[Month]) as reserve
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self join.

```
SELECT t.Emp_Code, t.Emp_Name, t.Month, t.Opening_Balance, t.Opening_Balance + n.Reserve
FROM Table1 t
JOIN Table2 n
ON t.Month = n.Month - 1
```